# Infinite loop in haskell program

Tags: haskell

The following code gives me a stack overflow error in some cases (ex `` hosum (\x->x `mod` 3) 1000 `` ) and I don't understand why. Could anyone explain this to me? (I am new to Haskell and I'd appreciate any help :) )

```
 hosum :: (Int -> Int) ->  (Int -> Int)
    hosum f  = (\x -> hs f x (- x))
            where hs :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
                  hs f 0 0 = f 0
                  hs f n m
                          | m <= n 
                          = f m + hs f n (m+1)
                          | n <= m 
                          = f n + hs f (n+1) m
                          | otherwise
                          = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack overflow is likely caused by the infinite recursion. Your guards are `m <= n` and `n <= m`; for every `n` and `m`, one of those is always true. Your `otherwise` is never reached, the recursion never terminates. You probably meant your guards to be `m < n` and `n < m`.

Your `hs` should therefore be

```
hs f 0 0 = f 0
hs f n m | m < n     = f m + hs f n (m + 1)
         | m > n     = f n + hs f (n + 1) m
         | otherwise = 0
```

Because of that last guard, you could even remove the pattern `hs f 0 0`; the `otherwise` catches that one.

Comment: oh ok, I understand. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I second removing the `hs f 0 0` case. It looks funny to see that as a base case, when `n,m` are _increasing_ (by 1) in each recursive call.